# How to add back side image as texture with SceneKit iOS

Tags: ios, 3d, textures, scenekit, scene

I am new to SceneKit and created an object I added an image as texture to object but it is showing on both the side front and back .what I want is to display another image behind it .is that possible to add two texture for an object?

```
    let scene = SCNScene()
    var planet : SCNGeometry
    let tempScene = SCNScene(named: "FrameOBJ.obj")
    planet = tempScene!.rootNode.childNodes[0].geometry!
    let material = SCNMaterial()

    let url = URL(string: "www.imageasf.com/123.png")
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)

    material.diffuse.contents = image
    material.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapMode.mirror
    material.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapMode.mirror
    material.isDoubleSided = true
    planet.materials = [material]
    let planetNode = SCNNode(geometry: planet)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planetNode)
    sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.allowsTranslation = true
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    sceneView.scene = scene
```

[Front View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALgtB.png)
    [Back View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXsqN.png)

Comment: Materials is an array of materials [material, material1, etc.], so yes you can have multiple materials - like a cube [front, right, back, left, top, bottom].  Since you called it a planet, assume you are trying to texture map a sphere?  Search scenekit texturemap planet - there are some videos on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done it by adding Material array .

```
    let tempScene = SCNScene(named: "untitled.obj")
    planet = tempScene!.rootNode.childNodes[0].geometry!

    var image = UIImage()
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.images123.jpg")!
    //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
    var node = SCNNode()

    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        image = UIImage(data: data)!
        node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.05, height: 1, length:1, chamferRadius: 0.5))
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image
        // do something with data
        // if the call fails, the catch block is executed
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    let  allMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    allMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "woods.png")

    let smallMaterial1 = SCNMaterial()
    smallMaterial1.diffuse.contents = image
    node.scale = SCNVector3(0.5,0.5,0.5)
    node.geometry?.materials = [smallMaterial1,allMaterial,smallMaterial1,smallMaterial1,smallMaterial1,smallMaterial1];

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    print(node.scale)
    print(scene.rootNode.scale)
    sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.allowsTranslation = true
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    sceneView.scene = scene
```